# ErrorDocument in htaccess with dynamic path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

I want to make my ErrorDocument dynamic.

Exemple:

> Current directory: /project ErrorDocument: ErrorDocument 403
>   /project/app.php
>
> Current directory: /client/admin ErrorDocument: ErrorDocument 403
>   /client/admin/app.php

This is my code:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

# Routing
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./app.php    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Error
ErrorDocument 403 /???????/app.php
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#errordocument)

> From 2.4.13, [expression syntax](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/expr.html) can be used inside the directive to produce dynamic strings and URLs.

So at least for 2.4.12 and earlier, you cannot create dynamic URLs. But you can have an .htaccess in every directory, where you want a specific error document, e.g.

```
# /project/.htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 /project/app.php
```

and

```
# /client/admin/.htaccess
ErrorDocument 403 /client/admin/app.php
```